my solana program keeps exeeding the allowed size limit for some reason. I've been dealing with this issue for days
I am running such a basic script and it keeps throwing this error. I have been dealing with it for days and cant figure it out. please help me
Lib.rs

declare_id!("BWSMgwKYXkdnqPJA3ZKqkXFvxeYhmbotpwEHnWBgjQH2");

#[program]
pub mod my_dex_project {
    use super::*;

    pub fn initialize(ctx: Context<Initialize>) -> Result<()> {
        msg!("Initialize function called");
        let data_account = &mut ctx.accounts.data;
        data_account.value = 0;
        msg!("Data account initialized with value: {}", data_account.value);
        Ok(())
    }
}

#[derive(Accounts)]
pub struct Initialize<'info> {
    #[account(init, payer = user, space = 8 + 8)]
    pub data: Account<'info, Data>,
    #[account(mut)]
    pub user: Signer<'info>,
    pub system_program: Program<'info, System>,
}

#[account]
pub struct Data {
    pub value: u64,
}

test script
    console.log("From Pubkey:", provider.wallet.publicKey.toString());
    console.log("New Account Pubkey:", dataAccount.publicKey.toString());
    console.log("Lamports:", lamports);
    console.log("Space:", 8 + 8);
    console.log("Program ID:", program.programId.toString());

    const createTx = new anchor.web3.Transaction().add(
      anchor.web3.SystemProgram.createAccount({
        fromPubkey: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        newAccountPubkey: dataAccount.publicKey,
        lamports,
        space: 8 + 8,
        programId: program.programId,
      })
    );

    createTx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
    createTx.feePayer = provider.wallet.publicKey;

    try {
      await provider.wallet.signTransaction(createTx);
      createTx.partialSign(dataAccount);

      const createSignature = await provider.sendAndConfirm(createTx, [dataAccount]);
      console.log("Create account transaction signature:", createSignature);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Failed to create account or send transaction:", err);
      return;
    }

    console.log("Sending initialize instruction");
    try {
      const tx = await program.methods.initialize().accounts({
        data: dataAccount.publicKey,
        user: provider.wallet.publicKey,
        systemProgram: anchor.web3.SystemProgram.programId,
      }).signers([dataAccount]).transaction();

      // Set the recent blockhash and fee payer
      tx.recentBlockhash = blockhash;
      tx.feePayer = provider.wallet.publicKey;

      // Sign the transaction
      tx.partialSign(dataAccount);
      await provider.wallet.signTransaction(tx);

      // Serialize the transaction to calculate its size
      const serializedTx = tx.serialize();
      const txSize = serializedTx.length;
      console.log(`Serialized transaction size: ${txSize} bytes`);

      const signature = await provider.sendAndConfirm(tx, [dataAccount]);
      console.log("Transaction signature:", signature);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error("Transaction failed:", err);
      if (err.logs) {
        console.error("Transaction logs:", err.logs);
      }
      return;
    }

    // Fetch and print the account data to confirm initialization
    try {
      const account = await program.account.data.fetch(dataAccount.publicKey);
      console.log("Account data:", account);

      // Verify the account data
      if (account && account.value === 0) {
        console.log("Account is initialized correctly.");
      } else {
        console.error("Account initialization failed.");
      }
    } catch (fetchErr) {
      console.error("Failed to fetch account data:", fetchErr);
    }
  });
});


can you please also include your exact error?

console.log('Serialized transaction size: ${txSize} bytes');
gives me
Serialized transaction size: 308 bytes
